# Spring data r2dbc blob - Blob data handling

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

I am using Reactive Spring Boot 2.5.4 with MySQL data source. I am not sure how to read/write blob with Spring data r2dbc.

Table - user_note

Columns - id, name, description

Here, description column is a blob data type.

My Domain class:

```
class UserNote {

  private final Integer id;   private final String name;   private final String description;

     // Constructor & Getter goes here }
```

Repository class,

```
public class UserNoteRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<UserNote, Integer> {
}
```

In my handler class, I am getting user input and creating domain and reading data back from the repository. Not sure how to handle the Blob data type with Spring data r2dbc.

Comment: Did you find out a way to achieve this?